# Distribution of the Ratio of i.i.d Uniform Random Variables Conditional on the Sum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, independence, uniform-distribution

Suppose X,Y are both Uniform on [0,1] and indpendent. I am interested in the distribution of X/Y conditional on X+Y=constant.
(Obviously, the constant must be <2.)

My hunch is that that distribution is essentially the same as the unconditional distribution of X/Y, but I have a hard time proving it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Letting $U=X/Y$ , $V= X+Y$. Are you interested in the distribution of $f(U|V)$ for values of $V$ in $[0,1]$ (conditioned on a variable), or in $f(U|V<1)$ (conditioned on an event) ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I meant the former: the distribution of U conditional on a specific value of V.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they are identically distributed, so it's a good thing you're having trouble proving your conjecture.  :)

Consider the full, x-y domain, the unit square in the x-y plane with each point equally likely (uniform density).  Your conditional then splits this domain along the diagonal from (0,1) to (1,0).

When you condition your distribution of X/Y on the lower triangle (x+y<1), you will generate large values of X/Y all along (near) the x-axis (when y is small, x/y blows up).

When you look at the upper triangle that you see you have a much lower density of these points that generate large values: just in the corner near (1,0) as opposed to all along the x-axis.

So, to summarize, your conditional (x+y<1) probability will have a distribution more heavily weighted to higher values than the overall distribution (which includes the upper triangular domain where the density is weighted to lower values of x/y).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, what I meant was the distribution of the ratio Y/X conditional on a particular value of the sum. So the conditioning event is X + Y = c, where c < 1, to make things easier—rather than X + Y < 1.

Answer (score 0):

Truncated of uniform is uniform so, $(X,Y)|X+Y<1$ is a uniform vector in the triangle of vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

Let $W=\frac{X}{Y}$, we want to compute its conditional cdf:
$$\mathbf{P}(W\leq w|X+Y<1)=\mathbf{P}(X\leq wY|X+Y<1)$$

For $w<0$ this probability is zero. For $w>0$, if you draw the areas you can compute the probability with the area ratio; i.e.
$$\mathbf{P}(W\leq w|X+Y<1)=\frac{w}{1+w}\mathbf{1}\{w>0\}$$

So the pdf is

$$f_{W|X+Y<1}(w)=\frac{1}{(1+w)^2}\mathbf{1}\{w>0\}$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually what I had in mind was the distribution of Y/X conditional on X+Y taking on a specific value c. To make things simpler, I was restricting attention to c < 1. But the more general solution, including for c > 1 would also be very welcome!